# How to cat and sed together?

Tags: sed, io-redirection, cat

I have this `cat` then `sed` operation:

```
cat ${location_x}/file_1 > ${location_y}/file2
sed -i "s/0/1/g" /${location_y}/file2
```

Can this be done in a single line?

I might miss such a way [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421909/cat-redirect-a-file-but-with-variable-expansions), but that explanation seems to me to deal with the opposite of that, and I fail too unite the above `cat` and `sed` into one operation without double ampersand (`&&`) or semicolon (`;`) and getting closer to assume it's not possible, but it's important for me to ask here because I might be wrong.

<sub>Not all readers are English speakers are familiar with the terms "ampersand" or "semicolon" so I elaborated on these.</sub>

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes:

```
sed 's/0/1/g' "$location_x/file_1" >"$location_y/file2"
```

Your code first makes a copy of the first file and then changes the copy using inline editing with `sed -i`. The code above reads from the original file, does the changes, and writes the result to the new file.  There is no need for `cat` here.

If you're using GNU `sed` and if the `$location_x` could contain a leading `-`, you will need to make sure that the path is not interpreted as a command line flag:

```
sed -e 's/0/1/g' -- "$location_x/file_1" >"$location_y/file2"
```

The double dash marks the end of command line options.  The alternative is to use `<` to redirect the contents of the file into `sed`.  Other `sed` implementation (BSD `sed`) stops parsing the command line for options at the first non-option argument whereas GNU `sed` (like some other GNU software) rearranges the command line in its parsing of it.

For this particular editing operation (changing all zeros to ones), the following will also work:

```
tr '0' '1' <"$location_x/file_1" >"$location_y/file2"
```

Note that `tr` always reads from standard input, hence the `<` to redirect the input from the original file.

---

I notice that on your `sed` command line, you try to access `/${location_y}/file2`, which is different from the path on the line above it (the `/` at the start of the path).  This may be a typo.

Comment: @Kusalananda I didn't understand this text at all `If you're using GNU sed and if the $location_x could contain a leading -, you will need to make sure that the path is not interpreted as a command line flag:`. What do you mean when $location_x could contain a leading `-`? Why would someone write `- $location_x` when it's not part of a command?

Comment: @user9303970 I added that bit aftor Stéphane commented, and it's only needed to protect the command in the case where _`$location_x` starts with `-`_ (as in `-mydir/somewhere`).  If you can guarantee that `$x_location` does _not_ start with `-`, then you may disregard that whole discussion.

Comment: @user9303970 It's good practice to be cautious when using user-supplied data in variables, but not needed if you have _full control_ over the contents of those variables and know for sure that it won't cause an issue.

Comment: @Kusalananda for the actual case I cope with I did: `sed "s/\${domain}/${1}/g" "~/myAddons/nginx_app" > "${s_a}/${domain}.conf"`. I read your answer at least 3 times and I understand that my code is good, but I'm still curious to know how can it be that the `sed` makes the change (where?), thus making the new redirected file to be created per that change. I am amazed of "how the Bash interpreter processes the command so sophisticated that the `sed` makes the new redirected file to be created with its own change. **intuitively** I'd assume "the `sed` should come in the end, not in the start".

Comment: @user9303970 But `sed` comes in the end (it's the only command). It will read from the given file, do its thing, and output the result. The shell handles the plumbing (the redirection to the output file).  Your initial second command is the same; it calls `sed` on a file, does the editing of it and outputs the result. The only difference is that by using `-i`, `sed` outputs the result to the same file that it was reading from.

Comment: Oh, I thought the `${x} > ${y}` is a command by itself. I think I miss only this --- where does `sed` does the change? I mean, I don't want to change the original file, but `sed` changes content already in it, so if the file isn't changed, I miss where `sed` makes that change.

Comment: @user9303970 I'm not quite sure I understand. `sed` reads from a file and produces changed output. That output is written to another file.  If you want to see _where_ the changes happened, you would have to compare the files, either by eye or by using something like `diff` (which shows the differences between two files). `$x >$y` is a command, it invokes whatever `$x` is and redirects the output of that to whatever `$y` is. The `$x` command however just do "output", and it's the shell that makes sure that this output goes into `$y`.

Comment: I mean: If `sed` doesn't change file A itself, but still changes something that you could find inside file A, where does `sed` stores the changed content, **before** it sends it to file B?

Comment: @user9303970 `sed` reads a single line from its input, applies its changes to that single line, and then outputs it. It then reads the next line. Technically, when you use `sed -i`, the output goes to a new temporary file that is later replacing the original file. With `sed` (no `-i`) the shell receives a _stream of data_ (individual lines) from `sed` and redirects them to a file on disk.  If you don't use a redirection (drop everything after `>` including the `>` itself), the shell sends the data to your terminal.

Comment: @user9303970 All of this is fairly basic knowledge and can be picked up from any text or tutorial describing how redirections and commands in general work in the Unix shell environment. I'm not saying this as a way of discrediting your question(s), but we have now gone far beyond the topic of the particular question that you asked.

Comment: Indeed we went far beyond that. Sorry for that, didn't mean that. I have never seen `sed` mentioned when I read on redirections in general and the abpve code seemed to me nonintuitive so I asked...

Comment: @user9303970 No worries. Any command that produces output on its _standard output stream_ may have that output redirected to a file. This includes `sed` and also `tr` that I mentioned in my answer. Do ask separate questions on the main site if there are specific things relating to this that you find unclear in the future (after having done your own research into it first).

Answer (score 1):

Alternate solution using `tee` just for a different approach:

```
cat "${location_x}/file1" |\
  tee "${location_y}/file2" |\
  sed -i "s/0/1/g"
```

Does the following:

-`cat`: Reads `${location_x}/file1` and pipes it to `tee`

-`tee`: Writes input from `cat` to `${location_y}/file2` and pipes it to `sed`

-`sed`: Runs your `sed` on the input from `tee`

Optional: if you want to write the output from `sed` to a file, just append `> /path/to/file` to overwrite, or `>> /path/to/file` to append.